# How will users be notified of future updates to the beta GUI wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Is the GUI wallet able to automatically check for updates and advise users to download the latest version, or will future updates be announced elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New releases get tagged on the [github page](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/releases), which is currently the freshest source of info on development progress.

Shortly after, downloads would be found on the "official" project site https://getmonero.org

Also, the Monero [sub-reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/) usually has important information stickied as the first post.

With this kind of software, it is probably not a good idea to implement auto-check as it could become a security vulnerability.